# Use one column as keys and another column as values to form an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Q1
            [1] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Q2
            [1] => 200
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Q3
            [1] => 300
        )

)
```

I want to have an array like this:

```
Array
 (
[Q1] => 100
[Q2] => 200
[Q3] => 300
)
```

So basically I want to split all arrays in one, and 0 key of all multi arrays will be key in the new array and 1 value in multi-array will be value in the new array. I tried with `array_combine`, but that does not work for me, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a function for that:

```
$result = array_column($array, 1, 0);
```

Failing that just loop:

```
foreach($array as $v) { $result[$v[0]] = $v[1]; }
```

Comment: Using this, Ive got this:
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 200
    [2] => 300
)

And I want this:

Comment: Array
 (
[Q1] => 100
[Q2] => 200
[Q3] => 300
)

Comment: That was not your question at all.  Where does Q1, Q2 etc. come from?

Comment: they are the 0 values in multi-arrays, please see again the question

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly what the code does, did you try it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Q2
            [1] => 200
        )

this should be [Q2] =>200

Comment: I use < PHP 5.3.0, and i must write manually array_column, this is what i write  function arrays_column($array,$column_name){
  return array_map(function($element) use($column_name){return $element[$column_name];}, $array);
    }

Comment: _I use < PHP 5.3.0_ Upgrade or give up.

Answer (score 1):

Use this straight-forward solution :

```
$arr = [
  ['Q1',100],
  ['Q2',200],
  ['Q3',300]
];

$res = array_combine(
                      array_column($arr, 0), 
                      array_column($arr, 1)
                    );

print_r($res);
```